Flutter Flow how to add list of list as firestore Object
Flutter Flow has a Firestore Section where you can link Firestore documents by defining proper data types
is there any way there to add a parameter as a list of list
for example:
  List<List<double>> routePath = [];

I created a new DataType object as List
for example:
RouthPath -> with param routhPath of type List<double>

and then add it in the parameter as List<Data(RouthPath)>
but I need something like

List< List < double > >


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
